# We Need New and Complete Page Tab Documentation. Please start here

Tags: tabs, facebook-page

The current Facebook Developers documentation for creating a Page Tab is incomplete  AND it looks like the process just changed again. Explanations on Stackoverflow are still not describing the process well.

Stack GURU who goes by the name of "DMCS" said that once you’ve created an app, you can paste the following string into the browser bar in order to tell Facebook to create a tab that points to that app.

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID &display=popup&next=THE_PAGE_TO_BE_ADDED_TO`

(1) What web page should we be on when we paste this?  The facebook page we want the tab to appear on?
(2) I’m assuming THE_PAGE_TO_BE_ADDED_TO = numbers at the end of the URL displayed in the browser bar when we're on the Facebook page we want the tab to display on. Yes?

For example, I would use 312467645451883 from the following URL:  `https://www.facebook.com/pages/Testing/312467645451883`

NOTE:  If all above it true, I tried this and received the following error message:

API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: redirect_uri URL is not properly formatted

My app settings follow.  Which is the redirect_uri URL and how is it improperly formatted?

Page Tab URL:  `http://consciousgardener.me/?page_id=80`  (non-SSL url)
Secure Page Tab URL:  `httpS://consciousgardener.me/?page_id=80`   (SSL url)
Page Tab Edit URL: (BLANK)

FINALLY… the URL paste seems very clunky.  Why isn’t there an API transaction to automate this?  It is a basic function and page creator needs to have.

Comment: William, I may have been mistaken about the `next=` parameter.  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/  It should be a link to the site mentioned in the APP's settings.  I went back and edited that unaccepted answer in hopes that that person, will accept it, with this new discovery. My humble apologies for giving out misguided information.

Answer (score 0):

> FINALLY… the URL paste seems very clunky. Why isn’t there an API
>   transaction to automate this? It is a basic function and page creator
>   needs to have.

The url is a secondary option to the FB.ui() call. See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>My Add to Page Dialog Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='fb-root'></div>
    <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
    <p><a onclick='addToPage(); return false;'>Add to Page</a></p>
    <p id='msg'></p>

    <script> 
      FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

      function addToPage() {

        // calling the API ...
        var obj = {
          method: 'pagetab',
          redirect_uri: 'YOUR_URL',
        };

        FB.ui(obj);
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```